# 見るように meaning in this song

Tags: particle-に, song-lyrics

The first two lines of Error by GARNiDELiA are

> 壊れてしまったモノを見るように
>
> おかしなことだと誰もが言う

I'm fairly confident it means, "Looking at (you) like something broken- everyone says it's strange." This would make it fit the tone of the rest of the song.

But I'm really having trouble piecing together this sentence. If it was:

> 壊れてしまったモノのように見るのが
>
> おかしなことだと誰もが言う

It would make sense to me. I've looked a lot online for an example of ように being used in the way in this song but I'm not finding anything beyond XがV-たように meaning "As X did V." But that's in the past tense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be most reasonable to understand it as

> 壊れてしまったモノを見るように（私を見ながら）

which is closer to your interpretation (except who is being looked at). The subject is *everybody*, so that it means *Looking at me as if they were looking at broken things, everybody says it is a strange thing*. Here what is described as strange is the speaker's ideas, behavior, etc.

> 壊れてしまったモノのように見るのが

would mean *Looking at (something) as if it were broken* and the second line would mean that is the strange thing.